# How to prove these equalities for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't get what to do with problems such as these:

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ so that:

$a+b+c=0$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=0$

Prove $a^3=b^3=c^3$

and

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ so that:

$a+b+c=7$, $ab+bc+ca=5$

Prove $a^3-7a^2+5a=b^3-7b^2+5b=c^3-7c^2+5c$

Can anyone give me the idea?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know a) the binomial theorem, or b) symmetric polynomials? Either way, just calculate. This is not *abstract algebra*, by the way. It's basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)$ and $a,b,c$ are the solutions  of
$$X^3-(a+b+c)X^2+(ab+ac+bc)X-abc=0$$

Comment: The first one is actually more straightforward: $a=-b-c \implies (b+c)^2+b^2+c^2=0\implies b^2+c^2+bc=0$.

Comment: And of course, this extends to the second question.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. those equalities are useful. I do not see yet why $abc=0$. After a lot of puzzling, I still can't get the result: $a^3=b^3=c^3$

Comment: @Powerlust, where it is told that $abc=0$. Let $abc=d$ and use this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas)

Answer (score 0):

For the first Question,

from $\displaystyle a=-b-c,$ we have $(-b-c)^2+b^2+c^2=0\iff b^2+bc+c^2=0$

Solving for $\displaystyle b, b=c\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3i}2=c\omega$ where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity.

So, we have $\omega^3=1\iff (\omega-1)(\omega^2+\omega+1)=0\implies \omega^2+\omega+1=0$

So, $a=-b-c=-c(1+\omega)=-c(-\omega^2)=c\omega^2$